# How to read tcp/ip headers in PHP?

Tags: php, tcp, header

I want to get the source endpoint .
Basically i want to block some ips by geting the port/ip from tcp/ip headers not from http header. Are there any built in methods for PHP to achieve that or i should do a workaround ?

Comment: Can't do that from PHP. Use a firewall instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just looking to block some IP from your website the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` variable holds the IP. If you need to block the request before it even gets to your webserver, GordonM is right, a firewall is what you need.

Comment: Yeah , the question was my mistake. Thought http header would also include source info and thought php's remote addr was from http header.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is too high up the networking stack to do this.  Once the PHP script starts the connection is already initiated.  If you want to block certain IP/port combinations then you have to do it at a lower level in the network stack.  A firewall is built for exactly this job, you need to set one up to enforce the restrictions you want.